# Possible to add tool tip to X-axis label in chart

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have tool tips on the labels of the x-axis in a chart?

My chart looks like this, and I would like to show a text when user puts mouse over the axis label e.g. 'VitaminA'

[image]